# How to copy files and directories without copying directory contents?

Tags: find, cp

I have a `find` command that selects some directories and files to be copied to a different location (with `--parents`). What I'd like is for the directories that are output by the `find` command to be copied without contents (but they should have the same ownership and mode).

I could limit `find` to files only with `-type f` or `! -type d`, but then directories would be created as needed with the default ownership and mode. If I use the `-r` option to `cp`, then directories are copied with the right ownership and mode, but also with all their files. Basically, I'd like for directories in the listing to result in copying only the directory metadata without its contents.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest tool to use I think is `pax`, as it has a `-d` option which says not to recurse when given a directory.

So to copy just directories, doing it in steps, so you can validate that the directories are copied do not copy the files as well you can do

```
find somewhere -type d | pax -wd  > archive.tar
tar vtf archive.tar
( cd somewhere_else && tar xpf - ) < archive.tar
```

Once you are happy, you can remove the intermediate printing of the contents of the archive (the tar vxf archive.tar) and replace the intermediate archive.tar file with a pipe.

Comment: Well, the better known `tar` tool can do the same thing with the `--no-recursion` option; e.g., `find ... -print0 | tar -c --no-recursion --null -T - | tar -C /destination/directory -x`

Comment: You may know the `--no-recursion` option to `tar`, but this is by no means standard.

Answer (score 1):

If you have GNU `find`, maybe something like

```
find path/to/dir -type d -printf '%P\0' | 
  rsync -0av --files-from=- path/to/dir/ path/to/newdir/
```

will do what you want (test by replacing `-0av` with `-0avn`).

Depending what your search criteria are, you might be able to use `rsync` alone with suitable filters e.g. to copy an entire directory structure

```
rsync -avn -f'+ */' -f'- *' path/to/dir/ path/to/newdir/
```

See for example [Linux: rsync Copy Directories Structures Tree Only](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-bsdosx-copying-directory-structures-trees-rsync/)